# Delete all RViz markers in a specific namespace

Tags: ros, markers.rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to delete all of the markers in a specific namespace without iterating through all ids that have been used in that namespace and deleting them individually? It seems that the DELETEALL action actually deletes everything in all namespaces, not just the given namespace.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263031/delete-all-rviz-markers-in-a-specific-namespace/) by [Dale McConachie](https://answers.ros.org/users/30596/dale-mcconachie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2017-06-01

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a big flaw in the RViz marker implementation but as far as I know there is no way except of deleting markers individually (which means you need to keep track of the markers you published...)

---

Originally posted by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) with karma: 382 on 2018-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2